# Error Opening Tasks from Outlook

Tags: workflow, excel, tasks, outlook, word

When I click on the "Open this task" in Outlook 2013.  I get the following message:

"Sorry We couldn't open https://...and the lists the URLs"

[image]

I can open the task from the tasks list in SharePoint.

I get the same issue when I open the document in Word or Excel and at the top of the screen when I click on the "Open this Task" button I get the same issue.

Comment: Did you customize the task InfoPath form at all?

Comment: What happens when you copy that exact link shown in the error and bring it up in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

We have now fixed this, it was actually quite simple:

1. Go to IE,
2. Internet Options,
3. Advanced,
4. Untick within the Security section the option called: `Do not save encrypted Pages to Disk`

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an error opening tasks from Outlook, there are a few troubleshooting steps you can take to resolve the issue:

Restart Outlook: Close the Outlook application completely and then reopen it. Sometimes, a simple restart can fix temporary glitches or conflicts that may be causing the error.

Update Outlook: Make sure you have the latest updates installed for Outlook. Microsoft regularly releases updates that address bugs and improve overall performance. Check for updates and install any available updates for Outlook.

Disable Add-ins: Add-ins can sometimes interfere with the proper functioning of Outlook tasks. Disable any recently installed or suspicious add-ins and check if the error persists. You can do this by going to the Outlook Options menu, selecting Add-ins, and then disabling or removing the relevant add-ins.

Repair Office Installation: If the issue persists, you can try repairing your Office installation. Open the Control Panel, navigate to Programs, and select Microsoft Office. From there, choose the Repair option and follow the prompts to repair the Office installation.

Create a New Outlook Profile: If none of the above steps resolve the issue, it may be worth creating a new Outlook profile. This will create a fresh configuration for Outlook, potentially resolving any profile-specific issues causing the error.

Regards,
Peter